# Busqueda y validacion de clientes en SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente estoy intentando buscar ciertos bancos en una tabla para saber si estan registrados, por ejemplo
BancoHN, BancoSA, BancoOcci y BancoPais

los unicos que tengo registrados son BancoHN y BancoPais

Entonces quiero un resultado que me diga, si el nombre BancoHN existe entonces que me muestre 2 columnas que me digan asi:

```
 NombreBanco                   EsCliente

  BancoHN                         Si
 BancoPais                        Si
```

Pero que tambiem me muestre las que no existen con la diferencia que en el campo "EsCliente" diga que no, asi:

```
 NombreBanco                   EsCliente

  BancoHN                         Si
 BancoPais                        Si     
 BancoSA                          No
 BancoOcci                        No
```

El query que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
SELECT 
c.FullnameLocal,

FROM dbo.Clients c  

WHERE  c.FullnameLocal IN ('BANCOHN','BANCOPAIS','BANCOSA','BANCOOCCI')
ORDER BY c.FullnameLocal
```

Estaba pensando en usar un IF EXIST para poder validar si el nombre existe entonces que diga que si es cliente, pero no se como hacer para que aunque no sea cliente siga colocando el nombre del banco y muestre el resultado como el cuadro de arriba que mostre

Comment: Y como son las tablas?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es tener una lista que pueda usarse como tabla para agregar a tu consulta. En el caso de SQL Server, lo puedes hacer con el constructor de tablas `VALUES`.

```
SELECT  b.NombreBanco,
        CASE WHEN c.FullnameLocal IS NULL 
            THEN 'No' 
            ELSE 'Sí' END AS EsCliente
FROM dbo.Clients c  
RIGHT JOIN (VALUES('BANCOHN'),('BANCOPAIS'),('BANCOSA'),('BANCOOCCI'))b(NombreBanco) ON c.FullnameLocal = b.NombreBanco
ORDER BY c.FullnameLocal;
```

Sin embargo, esto solo es rentable si los valores son pocos. En caso de que sigan aumentando, lo ideal es ponerlos en una tabla real.

Answer (score 0):

Existen muchas formas de calcular una expresión en función de unos datos. Personalmente la que más me gusta es [Case](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/case-evaluar-expresiones/), donde si la expresión a buscar es `true` entonces un resultado y si la expresión es `false` otro.

```
SELECT 
    c.FullnameLocal,
    CASE WHEN c.FullnameLocal IN ('BANCOHN','BANCOPAIS') 
        THEN 'Si'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END AS EsCliente
FROM dbo.Clients c  

WHERE  c.FullnameLocal IN ('BANCOHN','BANCOPAIS','BANCOSA','BANCOOCCI')
ORDER BY c.FullnameLocal
```

Comment: El problema es ver los bancos faltantes, no los que ya están.